Publish a new version of a lambda function only when the code of the lambda function changes
I want to publish a version of the lambda only when the source code of the lambda changes. Here is my terraform code.
# Package and upload the Lambda function code
data "archive_file" "this" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = var.lambda_source_dir
  output_path = var.archive_file_path
}

# Create the Lambda function
resource "aws_lambda_function" "this" {
  function_name = "${var.function_name}-${var.suffix}"
  filename      = data.archive_file.this.output_path
  handler       = var.handler
  runtime       = var.runtime
  memory_size   = var.memory_size
  timeout       = var.timeout
  role          = var.execution_role
  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.this.output_base64sha256

  environment {
    variables = {
      for key, value in var.lambda_env_variables : key => value
    }
  }

  dynamic "vpc_config" {
    for_each = (length(var.security_group_ids) > 0 && length(var.subnet_ids) > 0) ? [1] : []
    content {
      subnet_ids         = var.subnet_ids
      security_group_ids = var.security_group_ids
    }
  }

  layers = var.layers

  publish = var.publish

}


but every apply gives me such changes
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.lambda["test"].aws_lambda_alias.this will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_lambda_alias" "this" {
      ~ function_version = "7" -> (known after apply)
        id               = "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:*******:function:test-Backup:stage"
        name             = "stage"
        # (4 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

  # module.lambda["test"].aws_lambda_function.this will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_lambda_function" "this" {
        id                             = "test-Backup"
      ~ qualified_arn                  = "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:*********:function:test-Backup:7" -> (known after apply)
      ~ qualified_invoke_arn           = "arn:aws:apigateway:us-west-2:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:********:function:test-Backup:7/invocations" -> (known after apply)
        tags                           = {}
      ~ version                        = "7" -> (known after apply)
        # (26 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (3 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 2 to change, 0 to destroy.

What is wrong and how can I publish only when lambda source code changes? I also grouped some resources into a module and called the module for each lambda (not sure if this will affect or not).

Well, you haven't added a piece of configuration which seems to be a reason for the change. You provided the module code, but not how you are calling the module or why the function version changes in the alias resource.

Lambda function versions are not simply snapshots of executable code; most non-code changes cannot be applied without deploying a new version. See official doc

Terraform is going to build the archive zip file every time you run terraform apply, and the hash of that zip file is going to change every time. This is because zip files have metadata in them like the timestamp of their creation, so even if you zip the same files twice, the zip files will have different hashes.
You are using the hash of the zip file as the Lambda resource's source_code_hash value, which is used by Terraform to determine if the source code has changed. Since that value is changing every time, Terraform is going to deploy the Lambda function every time.
This is a very common problem when deploying Lambda functions with Terraform. I typically solve this by moving the zip file creation outside of Terraform, into a build script that I only run when the Lambda function code has actually changed. That raises other issues though, like forgetting to run the build script when the code has changed, preventing Terraform from updating the Lambda function with the new code.
A purely Terraform solution would be to get Terraform to calculate the hash of all your Lambda's source code, and use that as the source_code_hash value.
